# Black and white webcomic about a merman and a human guy who’s a potential friend/love interest

Tags: story-identification, webcomics, mermaids

I recently remembered a comic I saw on Tumblr a really long time ago, I don't know how to find it so I stumbled upon this site and maybe someone here remembers it.

The comic was drawn in black and white, the main characters were a creature looking merman, (his tail was proportionally quite long and his top half resembled the creature's from *[The Shape of Water](https://variety-com.cdn.ampproject.org/i/s/variety.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/shape-of-water-creature.jpg?resize=681,383)* movie) and a human guy, who's a potential friend/love interest.

I only saw maybe the first few chapters so I don't really know the plot but it was set in a river in some sort of jungle with the human character being on a wooden pier.

I really don't remember much as it has been at least 6 years since I read the comic.

Comment: I was going to posit https://m.webtoons.com/en/challenge/accidental-mer-der/list?title_no=290121&page=1&webtoon-platform-redirect=true, but that's more human-looking.